Is there a function $\phi$ such that $\int_0^t\int_0^t \phi(u,v) dudv=\int_0^t\psi(s)ds$?
Let $t$ be a positive real number and $\psi$ a positive function. I am looking for a function $\phi$ such that:  $$\int_0^t \int_0^t \phi(u,v) du\,dv=\int_0^t\psi(s)ds$$
Does such a function exist or not?

The question is ill-posed: whatever $f$ may be, the left-hand side will be a function of $t$; the right-hand side is a constant; thus, $t$ is bound to be a constant that satisfies the equation.

you have a reason , I was actually going to change it ! thank you for the remark ! @Rócherz

take a look now , @Rócherz

Hint: (Integration variables are dummy variables, so change either the $v$ on the left-hand side to $s$, or the $s$ on the right-hand side to $v$ for clarity.) Equate $\psi(v)$ to the inner integral on the left-hand side, then use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to try getting $\phi$ out of the integral somehow.

No, I didn't understand your answer but I think I can use the delta function here , u can take $ \phi(u,v) = \psi(u) \delta(u - v)$, what do you think ? @Rócherz

Geometrically I suspect that $\phi(u,v) = \frac1{2\max{u,v}}\psi(\max{u,v})$ works, if someone wants to try to confirm and justify this conjecture.

We claim that
$$
\phi(u,v) = \frac{\psi\bigl( \max\{u,v\} \bigr)}{2\max\{u,v\}}
$$
is such a function. To justify this, we start with the general differentiation rule
$$
\frac d{dt} \int_0^t h(t,v)\,dv = h(t,t) + \int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t}h(t,v)\,dv.
$$
We consider the special case
$$
h(t,v) = \int_0^t \phi(u,v)\, du,
$$
so that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h(t,v) = \phi(t,v)
$$
and thus
\begin{align*}
\frac d{dt} \int_0^t \int_0^t \phi(u,v)\, du\,dv &= \int_0^t \phi(u,t)\, du + \int_0^t \phi(t,v) \,dv.
\end{align*}
But notice that $\max\{u,t\}=t$ in the first integrand and $\max\{t,v\}=t$ in the second integrand, and therefore
\begin{align*}
\frac d{dt} \int_0^t \int_0^t \phi(u,v)\, du\,dv &= \int_0^t \frac{\psi(t)}{2t}\, du + \int_0^t \frac{\psi(t)}{2t} \,dv \\
&= \frac{\psi(t)}{2t} \biggl( \int_0^t 1\,du + \int_0^t 1\,dv \biggr) = \psi(t).
\end{align*}
Integrating both sides, it follows that
$$
\int_0^t \int_0^t \phi(u,v)\, du\,dv = \int_0^t \psi(s)\,ds
$$
(since both sides equal $0$ when $t=0$).

Thank you very much for your help !
